# removing non-numeric characters from a string

Tags: python

```
strings = ["1 asdf 2", "25etrth", "2234342 awefiasd"] #and so on
```

Which is the easiest way to get `[1, 25, 2234342]`?

How can this be done without a regex module or expression like `(^[0-9]+)`?

Comment: What if there is a string `"asdf"` in the input?  Should it be `0`, or not appear in the result list?

Comment: @Mikel, good point; the latter makes more sense to me, so I added a line to produce that result.

Comment: Why do you want a solution without using regular expressions? Usecase?

Comment: @ Mikel, There is always at least one digit at the beginning.

Comment: @Andreas Jung, Regex seems too much for such simple task. Wanted to find elegant solution without regex.

Comment: Thanks to all. I understand all the variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could write a helper function to extract the prefix:

```
def numeric_prefix(s):
    n = 0
    for c in s:
        if not c.isdigit():
            return n
        else:
            n = n * 10 + int(c)
    return n
```

Example usage:

```
>>> strings = ["1asdf", "25etrth", "2234342 awefiasd"]
>>> [numeric_prefix(s) for s in strings]
[1, 25, 2234342]
```

Note that this will produce correct output (zero) when the input string does not have a numeric prefix (as in the case of empty string).

Working from Mikel's solution, one could write a more concise definition of numeric_prefix:

```
import itertools

def numeric_prefix(s):
    n = ''.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c.isdigit(), s))
    return int(n) if n else 0
```

Comment: Thanks, "takewhile" is what I need

Answer (score 2):

```
new = []
for item in strings:
    new.append(int(''.join(i for i in item if i.isdigit())))


print new
[1, 25, 2234342]
```

Comment: But it will check each letter in string. "1 asdf 1" will turn into 11 instead of 1

Comment: If the string was "1 asdf 2" would the result be 1 or 2?

Comment: @CSZ: If the string is `"1 asdf 1"` what should (or do you expect) the result to be? 1 or 11? These are your strings...

Comment: See [itertools.takewhile](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) for one way to fix the `"1 asdf 2"` problem.

Comment: If you're going to give a list comprehension solution, might as well go all out (:  `[int(x) for x in ["".join([c for c in s if c.isdigit()]) for s in strings]]`

Answer (score 1):

Basic usage of regular expressions:

import re

strings = ["1asdf", "25etrth", "2234342 awefiasd"]

regex = re.compile('^(\d*)')

for s in strings:

```
  mo = regex.match(s)

  print s, '->',  mo.group(0)
```

1asdf -> 1

25etrth -> 25

2234342 awefiasd -> 2234342

Comment: -1.  Third line of question reads "How can this be done without a regex module or expression like (^[0-9]+)?"  It's pretty obvious CSZ is asking for an answer that does not use `re`.

Comment: Completely worthless thread since there is zero reason for *NOT USING* a regular expressions here.

Comment: Agreed.  But /that/ should have been your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you only want the leading digits? And you want to avoid regexes? Probably there's something shorter but this is the obvious solution.

```
nlist = []
for s in strings:
    if not s or s[0].isalpha(): continue
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if not c.isdigit():
            nlist.append(int(s[:i]))
            break
    else:
        nlist.append(int(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on sahhhm's answer, you can fix the "1 asdf 1" problem by using `takewhile`.

```
from itertools import takewhile

def isdigit(char):
  return char.isdigit()

numbers = []
for string in strings:
    result = takewhile(isdigit, string)
    resultstr = ''.join(result)
    if resultstr:
        number = int(resultstr)
        if number:
            numbers.append(number)
```

Comment: Note that Adeel Soomro's answer is probably simpler, provided it's OK for a string containing no digits to appear as `None` in the result list.